# Using a large PNG over google maps API

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, gps

I have a large PNG that I want to use as a map, but I want to be able to put a location marker on it to tell the user where they are. 
I'm really new to android development so how could this be done? Explanation or links would be nice, and I'd like the map to be scrollable as well. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to `overlay` an object (in this case a PNG image) on the Google map? If this is what you are trying to do, have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). There is also an example [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/drawing-an-image-as-a-map-overlay2).